# visual studio 2013 Could not copy "obj\Debug\.dll" to "bin\Debug\.dll".

Tags: angularjs, c#-4.0

[image: during building application i am getting following error]

Frequently I am getting this error. Even i have killed the process  so many
  times. Please help.

Comment: try restarting visual studio..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This usually happens when a file is in use by another process that runs with different user.

Try deleting these files manually (go to the debug folder and delete) and then build your solution.

Make sure you are not debugging while deleting.

Answer (score 2):

Try start visual studio with administrator privilege

Comment: I did the same but issue is still persisting.

Comment: Using administrator privilege can build successfully most of the time.Only something the error will prompt again.

Comment: No, the problem has nothing to do with admin or non-admin user!

Answer (score 0):

I experienced this on a project created in VS2010 and then opening it in VS2015. When I went back to VS2010 two things had changed:

1. In the project settings the debug workspace folder had been cleared.
2. The "use Visual Studio host" button had been unchecked.

I set the workspace to my debug folder and checked the "use host" checkbox and VS2010 was able to properly debug/code/debug multiple times again.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, the solution was:
Uncheck the "sign the ClickOnce manifests." in Procject Properties/Signing.  Some days I checked it to the test and I forgot to uncheck.

Answer (score 0):

Create a pre-build action in your project by going to project properties (right-click on the project in the solution explorer, and select the Properties option), select the Build Events tab. Add this code:

```
if exist "$(TargetPath).locked" del "$(TargetPath).locked"
if not exist "$(TargetPath).locked" move "$(TargetPath)" "$(TargetPath).locked"
```

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/5b71eb06-5047-483d-8fd3-b75c102d41e9/unable-to-copy-from-objdebug-to-bindebug?forum=Vsexpressinstall&prof=required

Comment: It is only able to run once, after that will get another unable to delete error.